# Getch is continuously outputing the same value

Tags: c++

I am building a small c++ program and am attempting the same functionality as seen in the options homepage of my battery logger batch program. Here are the two codes what I am using.

battery-logger.bat

```
@echo off
SET choice="none"
:USER_SELECTER
    CLS
    ECHO ===============================================================
    ECHO Battery logger                            
    ECHO ===============================================================
    ECHO Selected option: %choice%
    Choice /C codq /N /M "[C]reate power log | [O]pen report | [D]elete log | [Q]uit"
    set choice=%errorlevel%
    If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo :EOF IN CPP FILE THIS THE HYPOTHETICAL ARROW LEFT TO RETURN TO PREVIOUS MENU
    If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo :C
    If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :B
    If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo :A
    PAUSE
GoTo :USER_SELECTER
:C
ECHO DELETE IN CPP FILE THIS THE HYPOTHETICAL ARROW DOWN
GoTo :USER_SELECTER
:B
ECHO OPEN IN CPP FILE THIS REASSEMBLES ARROW RIGHT
GoTo :USER_SELECTER
:A
ECHO CREATE IN CPP FILE THIS THE HYPOTHETICAL ARROW UP
GoTo :USER_SELECTER
```

MENU.CPP

```
#include <iostream>    //required for all platforms
#include <stdio.h>     //linux/windows compatible
#include <stdlib.h>    //linux/windows compatiblE
#define KEY_UP 72      //windows compatible
#define KEY_DOWN 80    //windows compatible
#define KEY_LEFT 75    //windows compatible
#define KEY_RIGHT 77   //windows compatible
using namespace std;//required for all platforms
//test code
int TEST(){
    char c = 0;
    while(1){
        c=getch();
        switch(c){
            case KEY_UP: card='u';break;
            case KEY_DOWN: card='d';break;
            case KEY_LEFT: card='b';break;
            case KEY_RIGHT: card='f';break;
            default: card='p';break;//any non arrow key
        }
    }
    return c;
    }
} 
int main(){
    char a;
    while(1){
        a=TEST();
        cout<<a;
    }
}
```

console:
    � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � ...

I am looking for something such as `a d b v s z...`

Comment: Which value is it outputting?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `getch()` and `conio.h` in 2019? These have been obsolete since probably before you were born. Get yourself some proper standard I/O functions please.

Comment: _"I am getting a ASCII character with ? inside of a diamond."_ For what it's worth, that is not an ASCII character. It's probably the Unicode replacement character ("�").

Comment: Don't dump code like that into comments. Edit your question to provide the necessary detail in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: _"...hidden program code."_ Don't do that. We can't fix it if we can't see it.

Comment: There are a few problems here, particularly with your use of `break` -- but we need a [mcve] to properly identify all the errors.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica my C++ instructor said it is what our class uses sense it is a standard C++ input method.

Comment: @JTS Your instructor is lying to you.  Neither `getch` nor `conio.h` are defined in the C++ standard.  (They are available on a popular platform, but they are not standard.)

Comment: We don't want "the whole program".  We want a small demonstration program which does nothing useful, except display the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm not on windows, so I couldn't use getch, but I could use getchar(). I did a little bit of playing. Here's my final version:

```
#include <iostream>    //required for all platforms
#include <stdio.h>     //linux/windows compatible
#include <stdlib.h>    //linux/windows compatible

using namespace std;//required for all platforms


char TEST() {
    char c = getchar();
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char c;
    while(1) {
        c= TEST();
        cout << c << endl;
    }
}
```

Things that are different from your code, other than switching to use getchar() so it compiles under Ubuntu...

I used chars instead of ints.

I added an "endl" to the cout so it was more readable.

When I use chars like in the above code, and I type in abcd, it prints abcd (each on a line by itself, due to the endl.

If I switch it to use ints, then it does this:

```
^ g++ x.cpp -o x && x
abcd
97
98
99
100
10
-1
```

The first line is the compile and run. The second is me entering abcd (return). 97 is the ascii code for an a. (etc). 10 is the newline. -1 is the control-D I typed next (end of input).

Note that your code has other problems. Main is spelled maint. This is wrong. And you changed your variable name in your cout. So your code doesn't actually run without fixes.

Part of the problem may be converting back and forth between ints and chars, but because you clearly didn't actually run your code as written, I'm not sure if that's what you're doing.

Note that getch() might be returning a keycode. You shouldn't data convert it from an int to a char. You need to know more about how getch() works. Maybe a windows programmer will have more info.

Or maybe it's just your data conversion back and forth. Maybe my code helps.